# Azure cant pull images from a private registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks

im sincerelly burned, i dont know where else or what to try.

Im trying to connect my azure kuberentes cluster (which is in rancher) to our harbor registry, with no luck, it seems that something is blocking and azure cant reach the registry.

Here's what i've tried:

Added the registry credentials correctly in rancher, which did nothing since every time i try to pull an image i get `ImagePullBackOff: Back-off pulling image` error

Inside an aks node (via ssh):

Ping resolves the hostname and ip, but fails to actually ping the server

Curl just timeout with empty response

Nslookpu brings the info of the server

Docker login (server) responds `net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

is there something that im missing? i sincerelly dont know what more to try

Comment: Can you please run "az acr check-health -n ACR_REGISTRY" from one of your nodes and share the output? (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-faq#docker-pull-fails-with-error-nethttp-request-canceled-while-waiting-for-connection-clienttimeout-exceeded-while-awaiting-headers)

Comment: Which private registry do you use? Do you create the credential for the private registry?